# Using a Resource from a Nested Stack in Another Nested Stack with DependsOn

Tags: amazon-web-services, dependencies, aws-cloudformation

I have been refactoring what has become a rather large stack because it is brushing up against size limits for CloudFormation scripts on AWS. In doing so I have had to resolve some dependencies (typically using Outputs) but I've run into a situation that I have never run into before...

How do I use a resource created in one nested stack (A) in another nested stack (B) when using `DependsOn`?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57959202/aws-cloudformation-how-to-dependson-resource-from-another-nested-stack) is a duplicate *question* but the answer does not fit because it doesn't actually resolve the issue I have, it takes a different approach based on that particular user's needs.

Here is the resource in nested stack A:

```
EndpointARestApi:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      Body:
        Fn::Transform:
          Name: 'AWS::Include'
          Parameters:
            Location: !Join ['/', [ 's3:/', !Ref SharedBucketName, !Ref WorkspacePrefix, 'endpoint.yaml' ]]
```

And here is the `DependsOn` request in stack B:

```
EndpointUserPoolResourceServer:
    Type: Custom::CognitoUserPoolResourceServer
    DependsOn:
      - EndpointARestApi
      - CustomResource ## this resource is in the same stack and resolves properly
```

This occurs with one other resource I have in this stack so I am hoping that I can do this easily. If not, I believe I would have to refactor some more.

Comment: DependsOn work only for resources in same stack. You can't use it across different stacks or between nested stacks.

Comment: @Marcin can I put the resource in the primary CFN and have it used by nested stacks?

Comment: Yes, you can pass parameters to your nested stacks. These parameters can be based on the resources from the primary template.

Comment: Another possibility could be to add a `DependsOn: Stack A` attribute to the CloudFormation resource for stack B in the primary stack. This way, stack B will be created after stack A.

Comment: @berenbums Yes! Hopefully I can test that tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in comments I moved the `DependsOn` statement up to the primary CFN script in the resource requiring the dependency and made sure the dependency was on the other resource, not the nested resource, like this:

```
Primary
  ResourceA
  ResourceB
    DependsOn: ResourceA
```

Which ends up looking like this in the CloudFormation script:

```
EndpointUserPoolResourceServer:
    Type: "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack"
    DependsOn:
      - EndpointARestApiResource
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        AppName: !Ref AppName
        Environment: !Ref Environment
        DeveloperPrefix: !Ref DeveloperPrefix
        DeployPhase: !Ref DeployPhase
```